# Convolution output signal is very large, do I need to scale inputs or outputs?

Tags: matlab, filters, fft, audio, convolution

I am writing some simple matlab code to refresh my convolution knowledge (it has been awhile) in regards to DSP.
I have an input signal x and a filter -

```
x = [1 3 6 2 8];
h = [2 9 5 3];
y=conv(x,h);
```

which results in

```
y = [2 15 44 76 73 100 46 24];
```

I understand these values are large because convolution has lots of multiplication and addition, however
if this was an audio signal I was trying to filter, these values seem very large.

Do I need to scale the input filter or output signal some how?  If so which one and by how much?

Answer (score 1):

In practice you would make sure that your filters don't have very large gains, at least not over a large frequency range. The filter you're using in the given example has a maximum gain of almost $26$ dB (at DC), and the gain is no less than $12$ dB for any frequency. I.e., you're applying a flat gain of $12$ dB, and on top of that you boost a relatively wide band around DC by another $14$ dB. This is not what a typical filter for audio signals would do, unless you make sure that the input signal is small enough and the additional gain is really needed.

Comment: ok, so there is nothing I would have to do to this filter in theory.  I understand somewhat how to calculate filter coefficients so I get the gain and phase I want.  I just wanted to tell if I am missing a step in this process or not.  I guess this was just a really bad example filter to use.

Comment: @scott: You would normally scale that filter such that its average gain is not that large, but it was indeed not a very representative example for audio processing.